# What's the most common set up for running Node.js and Express.js in a production environment?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

So as a developer I've mostly worked with PHP for the back end (running on Apache) and using HTML, CSS and JavaScript on the Front End. Now I've begun to dip my toes into the work of Node.js, Express.js and Angular.js.

So I'm curious how would you set up Node and Express in a production environment. I know Node is not a Web server although it can serve files, but what does a typical production environment for this stack look like?

Thanks so much in advance.

Floyd

Comment: your question isn't very clear.  It's true that node isn't a web server, but the app you write using the node engine *is*.

Comment: Hmm. So if I'm using Express.js, your saying Express.js would acted as my Webserver?

Comment: Nginx will be your web server not express

Comment: @SarasArya there is no reason to use nginx.  node's http module (which express uses) is a fully functional and featured http server.  I have worked multiple places where the node http server listens on port 80s and 443 directly.

Comment: Okay, so I would still need a web server like Nginx. That's what I was thinking but it's hard to tell since I feel like most documentation is geared for people working in a development environment locally. I was looking for information about how to run this on my web server under my own domain.

Comment: no, you absolutely *do not* need a web server.  You can use a server like nginx, but it is in no way at all a requirement.

Comment: Express.js isn't a web server either, it is an express package that makes configuring your app to use the `http` module of node easier.  your app is still the web server.

Comment: @tkone Yeah but that's now how you run it in production. The OP asked how you run it in production. All the production system I have come across use some kind of web server either for load balancing or reverse proxy if the OP wants to use the same domain to run multiple apps, which is a common use case in any production environment

Comment: @SarasArya your answer may work, but it is a bit misleading.  You directly admit that the node app is a web server by suggesting that you use ngnix as a reverse proxy to the port the app is running.  You aren't using ngnix to *host* the app, you are using ngnix to *proxy* the app, which isn't the same thing.  If someone doesn't need reverse proxy, then the additional server isn't necessary or useful.

Comment: Okay, I think this is why I'm asking the question. I'm confused as to what would a typical set up be. I just finished developing a small app with Node, Express and Angular and I was thinking of putting it up on my Linux server (which is running Apache) but I have no idea if that's possible, or rather if that's a good idea. For instance would use Node to run my Express app as a demon?

Comment: @Showcaselfloyd I edited my answer. Please see and comment if you need more guidance on that matter. There are more basic ways of doing things but I am focusing on the easiest one to get started.

Comment: @Claies I know that it's not the most basic answer, you can run a nodeJS app without Nginx true and agreed 100%.  but my point is, its easy to maintain manage and scale with Nginx which is the rationale in a production server.

Comment: @SarasArya that is literally how we ran (and continue to run) in production. i've even thrown a load-balancer in front, but the machine is still just running node.  nothing else.  load balancing or reverse proxying are separate issues.

Comment: @tkone that's cool. Well, production setup can vary company to company. You told your setup and I told mine. I would also like to add the correct point is you don't need Nginx to serve your web application. It is one of the available web servers my company chooses to run in production hence the bias towards Nginx nothing else. You are absolutely correct. Nginx is not mandatory but it makes my life easy.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite broad. I'll give you an idea of how I setup everything using digital ocean as an example.

**Deployment**

[Digital ocean setup guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04)

The important part is that nginx will be your reverse proxy. Once you've done this, remember to:

- Not leave any console.logs() inside your code. They are synchronous methods and will slow down the code.
- Set the environment variable node_env to production.
- Serve static files from nginx if possible.
- Use helmet middleware for express for security.
- Resolve www vs non-www at the nginx layer.

You will still need to install mongodb, rethinkdb, etc seperately. If you wish you can also use a database service provider like mongolab.

**Scaling**

The above mentioned setup is pretty alright for most websites but if you are hitting speed bottlenecks or your app is crashing, you may want to use:

- toobusy. Its a middleware to send away requests when the load is too high.
- Check the order of your routes. Ideally `app.use(express.static());` should be just before your 404 handler.
- Or serve static assets from s3 or somewhere else.
- Look up the cluster module. There are packages which make it easier to use though.
- Use cloudflare for dns. Highly recommended.
- Use varnish for cache.

**Notes:**
Other people have pointed out that you can use nodejs by itself without nginx. However most people recommend using nginx in production environments. Heck some providers like appfog have nginx as a default.

Answer (score -1):

All the packages you named are available through Node Package Manager (NPM). NPM usually comes with node, and is pretty much essential for all Node.js projects. You can install apps like

npm install express

Which installs express and all its dependencies. And if you want to be able to replicate your environment on any computer, run

npm init

and add --save flag to all install commands. This adds it to a file called package.json, and the next time you want to install everything from scratch, you can include your package.json, and just run

npm install

in the directory.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty familiar with how to install these packages, I guess what I'm asking is what type of web server environment is typical for this stack. Meaning, in a LAMP stack I would use Apache to serve my html pages, and  process the PHP on them. What would the Node version of this be like.

Comment: That is kind of what express is for. You can use it to serve dynamic and static pages, as well as create APIs. I guess good equivalent of the LAMP stack is the MEAN stack. This is MongoDB as a database, Express as a framework for the web app, Angular to create the dynamic pages, and Node to tie it all together (access database, set up express app, serve data to angular).

Comment: Okay, so I think this is what I'm having trouble wrapping my head around. In a LAMP environment you typically have Apache running as a service and listening on port 80 for requests. Would Express take the place of Apache in this scenario? Also does this mean you can run a MEAN stack on a Linux server without Apache or Nginx?

Comment: Yes, you can set Express to listen to whatever port pleases you. Express can run on any OS as far as I'm aware, its all the same because its run within Node. Check out https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4, it gives you a pretty good idea of what Express is doing.

Answer (score -2):

Having asked this question and not getting a  perfect example I would like to explain this with more hardware oriented way(that's how production works. On real servers).
Let's say you have a droplet a $5 one from the digital ocean with ubuntu installed on it and nothing else.

You buy a domain name(www.example.com). You buy a server from any company. They give you an IP address(let us say 12.133.222.59). Now you must be running your node app on let's say port 8000. You run it by typing node app.js and then go to the browser and run localhost:8000. Your app is now running. Excellent. Now what you need to do it is put your app on the server and run it so it will run on 12.133.222.59:8000 but that's not how you want it. You want it like www.example.com and it should open up the localhost:8000 page for you am I right? 
If yes. You need to link www.example.com with 12.133.222.59:8000. 
How you do that. Well, there are many ways. I like the easy one. Which according to me is using Nginx. It will serve your web application at a particular address, which much setup. 
Now how to use Nginx to do that is beyond the scope of the question. But if you want me to continue i will.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. This sort of answers my questions, but I think what I was looking for was something more about what would be the best way to run a Node + Express App on my Linux server. From what I can tell, I can do it with Apache and just use proxy proxy_http. Similar to how I would run PHP and Nginx together on a server. One things for sure, I found that it seems there's many ways to do this type of thing. Anyhow, I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: If you ask me best way I would still say to go with Nginx, but then again it's your choice. Many popular companies like LinkedIn run their backend with Nginx + NodeJS. But I wouldn't force you. If you feel you are confident with Apache go ahead. May the force be with you.